# How do I update collectionview based on added info to firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, uicollectionview

Im having a problem in my app, I am working on a Twitter/Instagram like app that posts a pic and then retrieves it in the "Home" section. But, I cant find a way to make the collection view update when the new post is added in firebase. I tried self.collectionview.reloadData(), it didn't work, I tried self.posts.removeAll() and then self.fetchPosts() to retrieve it again and it didn't work. I've been working on this problem for months and just can't find a possible solution without having to pay $$ for a "short problem".
Thanks in advance!

Here is my code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var collectionview: UICollectionView!

var posts = [Post]()
var following = [String]()
lazy var refreshControl: UIRefreshControl? = {
    let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    refreshControl.tintColor = UIColor.gray
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refreshList), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
    collectionview.addSubview(refreshControl)
    self.collectionview.reloadData()

    return refreshControl
}()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setupNavigationBarItems()
    fetchPosts()
    collectionview.refreshControl = refreshControl

}

func setupNavigationBarItems() {
    navigationItem.title = "Home"
}

@objc func refreshList() {
    let deadline = DispatchTime.now() + .milliseconds(1000)
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: deadline) {

        self.collectionview.reloadData()
        self.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
        print("reloaded...")
    }
    self.collectionview.reloadData()
}

@objc func fetchPosts() {

    let ref = Database.database().reference()

    ref.child("users").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

        let users = snapshot.value as! [String : AnyObject]

        for (_,value) in users {
            if let uid = value["uid"] as? String {
                if uid == Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
                    if let followingUsers = value["following"] as? [String : String]{
                        for (_,user) in followingUsers{
                            self.following.append(user)
                        }
                    }
                    self.following.append(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)

                    ref.child("posts").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snap) in

                        let postsSnap = snap.value as! [String : AnyObject]
                        for (_,post) in postsSnap {
                            if let userID = post["userID"] as? String {
                                for each in self.following {
                                    if each == userID {
                                        let posst = Post()
                                        if let author = post["author"] as? String, let likes = post["likes"] as? Int, let pathToImage = post["pathToImage"] as? String, let postID = post["postID"] as? String {

                                            posst.author = author
                                            posst.likes = likes
                                            posst.pathToImage = pathToImage
                                            posst.postID = postID
                                            posst.userID = userID
                                            if let people = post["peopleWhoLike"] as? [String : AnyObject] {
                                                for (_,person) in people {
                                                    posst.peopleWhoLike.append(person as! String)
                                                }
                                            }

                                            self.posts.append(posst)
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                                self.collectionview.reloadData()
                            }
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        }

    })
    ref.removeAllObservers()
}

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.posts.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "postCell", for: indexPath) as! PostCell

    cell.postImage.downloadImage(from: self.posts[indexPath.row].pathToImage)
    cell.authorLabel.text = self.posts[indexPath.row].author
    cell.likeLabel.text = "\(self.posts[indexPath.row].likes!) Likes"
    cell.postID = self.posts[indexPath.row].postID


    for person in self.posts[indexPath.row].peopleWhoLike {
        if person == Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid {
            cell.likeBtn.isHidden = true
            cell.dislikeBtn.isHidden = false
            break
        }
    }

    return cell
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this

```
ref.child("posts").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snap) in
```

with

```
ref.child("posts").observe(of: .childAdded, with: { (snap) in
```

to be able to listen to every added post

Comment: how do i make that for my refresher?